# How to add an editor on each row of a column tree

Tags: asp.net, extjs, ext.net

I'm using Ext.NET 1.2. I need to create a `ColumnTree` in my system.

**Markup**

```
<ext:ColumnTree ID="colProjects" runat="server" RootVisible="false" Title="Projetos" EnableDD="true">    
    <TopBar>
        <ext:Toolbar ID="Toolbar1" runat="server">
            <Items>
                <ext:Button ID="btnExpandAll" runat="server" Text="Expandir Tudo">
                    <Listeners>
                        <Click Handler="#{colProjects}.expandAll();" />
                    </Listeners>
                </ext:Button>
                <ext:Button ID="btnCollapseAll" runat="server" Text="Recolher Tudo">
                    <Listeners>
                        <Click Handler="#{colProjects}.collapseAll();" />
                    </Listeners>
                </ext:Button>
            </Items>
        </ext:Toolbar>
    </TopBar>        
    <Loader>
        <ext:TreeLoader>
            <UIProviders>
                <ext:TreeNodeUIProvider Alias="col" ClassName="<%# ColumnTree.ColumnNodeUI %>" AutoDataBind="true" />
            </UIProviders>
        </ext:TreeLoader>
    </Loader>            
    <Columns>
        <ext:ColumnTreeColumn Header="Nome" Width="330" DataIndex="Name" />
        <ext:ColumnTreeColumn Header="Sistema" Width="100" DataIndex="ProjectGroup" />
        <ext:ColumnTreeColumn Header="Recurso" Width="100" DataIndex="SprintOwner" />
        <ext:ColumnTreeColumn Header="Status" Width="100" DataIndex="Status" />            
    </Columns>              
</ext:ColumnTree>
```

I populate it dynamically via codebehind which works well. The last column needs to be editable and updated to the database but I have no idea whether or not it is possible to do so. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With 1.2 version of Ext.NET you can't do this.

Found at Ext.NET forum message from mcgill, author of Ext.NET.

http://forums.ext.net/showthread.php?12251-CLOSED-ColumnTree-cell-editing

> At the moment Editors are not supported on the  Component.
>
> We did some preliminary investigation and will add this as a Feature
>   Request to implement in a future release.
>
> There is a problem though... I think this functionality may be
>   included in the next major release of Ext.NET (v2). But that release
>   is a ways off yet.

As a solution I recommend you to look at this example: http://examples.ext.net/#/GridPanel/Data_with_Details/Form_Details/

You can do this in your project for grid and without unnecessary request to the server.